# Riley again, this adds flavor to food

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My prefix a conjunction is,
an alternative thing.
My infix, add an l to it,
there's royalty, and king.
My suffix negative it is,
can't add another hint.
But all the words together fit
and I'm a spice, like mint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is.... (drumroll)

> Oregano

Prefix:

> Or is a this OR that choice conjuction

Infix:

> Rega with an l is regal or seeming like royalty

Suffix:

> No is a rejection and considered "negative"

Total word:

> Oregano is a type of herb

Comment: (accidentally clicked a button)

Comment: Aye aye what have you done?